# Pointcut that will capture constructor calls

Tags: aop, aspectj

I am trying to define a pointcut which will capture all the constructor calls, regardless of the modifier, return type, or class. I have used the following code

`after():execution(* * * .new(..))`

I am having an error :

> Syntax error on token "*", "(" expected.

Can anybody suggest what may be the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the middle star "*". It does not make sense to specify a return type for a constructor call because it is clear that the constructor will always return an instance of the class it is defined for.

```
after() : execution(* *.new(..))
```

BTW, you should also remove the whitespace before ".new".

Comment: error at after() : execution(* *.new(..)){
                     
Syntax error on token "*", "method name (not constructor)" expected

Comment: I just disregard your rude comment and unfriendly tone. I admit that I may have overlooked a star since the syntax says quite little to me and I do not do mindless copy-paste rather I want to understand the logic behind it and yes, I need to familiarize myself with AspectJ.

Comment: I did not mean to be rude, but it struck me as rather odd that the original poster had one star and one space too many and you one star too few. To me it just looks like you are writing code you do not even understand the very basics of. Actually I love to help, especially with AspectJ, but I am not a replacement for a parser or compiler. Please forgive me for being a bit blunt here, I did not mean to offend you.

Comment: Why the downvote for an absolutely correct an even accepted answer? Downvotes are reserved for wrong or sloppy answers showing a significant lack of  effort or diligence. My answer is correct and even explains why others are wrong.

Comment: quite late to the party, but upvoted, because I don't see why it has no upvote yet. It's a correct answer and is helping.