# Spring AspectJ point cuts

Tags: java, spring, constructor, pointcut

I am in need of writing a *Single* pointcut to intercept the constructor of all the classes. The actual need is to intercept all the beans where in  no other methods apart from the init() and the constructor are invoked. For the init it is straight forward. But since the constructor name changes with the class name writing a single point cut is getting tough.

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15797331/pointcut-that-will-capture-constructor-calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A constructor in AspectJ syntax is represented by the "method name" `new`, i.e. if you want to capture all constructor executions the pointcut is

```
execution(* *.new(..))
```

Comment: Varun wrote a comment, not an answer. And his link points to a question which has my own answer as the accepted one anyway. ;-)